# Polynomial time reduction Hamiltonian path to TSP

Tags: np-complete, hamiltonian-path

is there a polynomial time reduction from Hamiltonian Path to TSP? If so, could you tell me?

Thank you in advance!
Toby

Comment: This is not particularly well-suited to math.stackexchange.com since cstheory.stackexchange.com already exists.

Comment: There are other polynomial reductions shown here, so I thought it would be the right thing to ask for help here

Comment: Please dont' use unnecessary abbreviations such as HAMPATH that are completely uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of *Hamiltonian cycle* is a graph $G=(V,E)$ with finite vertex set $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Let $G^\prime=(V,W)$ be a complete  weighted digraph with the same vertex set and weight matrix $W=(w_{ij})$ ($w_{ij}$ gives the weight of the edge from $i$ to $j$) given by 
$$
w_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }(i,j)\in E;\\
2 & \text{if }(i,j)\notin E.
\end{cases}
$$
There is a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$ if and only if there is a cycle of length at most $n$ in $G^\prime$.

For the last part of the argument, [you also need this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7130/reduction-from-hamiltonian-cycle-to-hamiltonian-path).

---

**Addendum (direct reduction)**: An instance of *Hamiltonian path* is a graph $G=(V,E)$ with vertex set $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Let $G^\prime=(V\cup\{0\},W)$ be a complete weighted digraph with weight matrix $W$ given by
$$
w_{ij}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }i=0\text{ or }j=0;\\
1 & \text{if }(i,j)\in E;\\
2 & \text{if }(i,j)\notin E.
\end{cases}
$$
There is a Hamiltonian path in $G$ if and only if there is a cycle of length at most $n-1$ in $G^\prime$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, there is no direct reduction from hamiltonian path to tsp? Instead, you have to reduce hamiltonian path to hamiltonian cycle first, then reduce hamiltonian cycle to travelling salesman problem, right?

Comment: No, it's a simple modification of the above. I have added it.